# Transfert project from Codeplex/TFS to SourceForge/Git with Visual Studio 2015 / TFS 2015

Tags: git, tfs, codeplex, sourceforge, myprettycms

I need to transfert the open source cms MyPrettyCMS source code from Codeplex to Source forge.

MyPrettyCMS sources (http://myprettycms.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) was handled with Visual Studio 2013 directely connected to the CodePlex TFS.

Now I have Visual Studio 2015 and TFS 2015. I know that the trend is Git ans Sourceforge so, I decided to move my project.

I would manage source with my TFS AND with Sourceforge.

I created a Team Project in my TFS and a Project in sourceforge https://sourceforge.net/p/myprettycms2016/code/ref/master/), for both I selected Git as source code management system.

I cloned locally my empty tem project and I copied source code downloaded from Codeplex.

My question is How I can Keep source in both TFS and Sourceforge repositories ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this:

> **git-tfs** is a two-way bridge between TFS (Team Foundation Server) and git, similar to git-svn. It fetches TFS commits into a git
>   repository, and lets you push your updates back to TFS. More details
>   about it: https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs